# Как вставить скрипт Vue js

Tags: vue.js

```
<script data-b24-form="inline/9/zgsrsi" data-skip-moving="true">
    (function(w,d,u){
            var s=d.createElement('script');s.async=true;s.src=u+'?'+(Date.now()/180000|0);
            var h=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];h.parentNode.insertBefore(s,h);
    })(window,document,'{{ ссылка на код }}');
</script>
```

Хочу вставить этот скрипт в компонент Vue js, не смог найти в гугле ответ

Comment: Чем не устраивает вариант "просто поместить этот тег в шаблон компонента"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно вот так

```
<template>
  <div></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    const s = document.createElement("script");
    s.innerHTML = `
       (function(w,d,u){
           console.log(123)
       })();
      `;
    document.body.appendChild(s);
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 0):

Я использовал

```
<template>
  <div>
    <script
            type="application/javascript"
            data-b24-form="inline/9/zgsrsi"
            data-skip-moving="true"
          >
            (function (w, d, u) {
              var s = d.createElement("script");
              s.async = true;
              s.src = u + "?" + ((Date.now() / 180000) | 0);
              var h = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
              h.parentNode.insertBefore(s, h);
            })(
              window,
              document,
              "{{ссылка}}"
            );
    </script>
 </div>
</template>
```

Указав type="application/javascript"